# left join tables, use only one row from left table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am trying to join two tables in MS SQL, but I need to join only unused rows.

**Example:**

```
table1              table2
key  -  value  |     key  -  value
1    -  1      |     1    -  1
2    -  2      |     2    -  1
3    -  3      |     3    -  3
4    -  3      |     4    -  4
```

sql code

```
select * from table1
left outer join 
(
    select * from 
    (
        select *, row_number() over(partion by value order by key) as rwno
        from table2
    ) as t2 
    where rwno = 0  -- this eliminates first two rows in table2
) as tab2
on
    table1.key = tab2.value
```

this query returns

```
table1.key  -  table1.value  -  tab2.key  -  tab2.value
1           -  1             -  1         -  1
2           -  2             -  null      -  null
3           -  3             -  3         -  3
4           -  3             -  3         -  3
```

In this return is twice used row 3 from table2

I need answer like (without duplicity)

```
table1.key  -  table1.value  -  tab2.key  -  tab2.value
1           -  1             -  1         -  1
2           -  2             -  null      -  null
3           -  3             -  3         -  3
4           -  3             -  null      -  null
```

Is there any possibility to reach this return using MS SQL query.

Comment: why should there be no match where key = 4, it seems unique to me?

Comment: this value from table2 has been already used in row 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent joining duplicate rows again, you need to assign them a number and join on this number like this, can almost promise this will not perform well on a huge table:

```
DECLARE @table1 table([key] int, value int)
DECLARE @table2 table([key] int, value int)

INSERT @table1
VALUES(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,3)

INSERT @table2 VALUES(1,1),(2,1),(3,3),(4,4)

;WITH CTE1 as
(
  SELECT
    *, 
    row_number() over(partition by value order by [key]) secondkey
FROM @table1
), CTE2 as
(
  SELECT *,
  row_number() over(partition by value order by [key]) secondkey
  FROM @table2
)
SELECT 
  CTE1.[key], CTE1.value, CTE2.[key], CTE2.[value]
FROM CTE1
LEFT JOIN
  CTE2
ON 
  CTE1.[key] = CTE2.value 
  and CTE1.secondkey = CTE2.secondkey
```

Result:

```
key  value  key  value
1    1      1    1
2    2      NULL NULL
3    3      3    3
4    3      NULL NULL
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the solution I looked for

Answer (score -1):

I think you just want a `left join`:

```
select t1.key, t1.value, t2.key, t2.value
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.key = t2.key and t1.value = t2.value;
```

If you want non-matches in `table1` as well, then use `full outer join` instead of `left join`.

Comment: Sorry, the keys in tables are only simplifications and they are not related, I cannot use it your way

Comment: @PetrEhler . . . This query quite explicitly answers the question you have asked.  If you have another question, I would suggest that you ask another question with appropriate sample data and desired results.

Comment: Lets assume that in the table2 are key values a,b,c,d. The key in table2 is not related to key in table1.